# Parallel Spark run seems not have the correct object map being used

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, thread-safety

I am pretty new on Spark (not even sure my issue is related to Spark). I have code like below.

SparkRunner.java

```
Map<Integer, ObjectDomain> allObjectDomains = loadAllDomainData();

Broadcast<Map<Integer, ObjectDomain>> partialObjectDomain = sc.broadcast(allObjectDomains);         

JavaRDD<Result> resultRDD = inputRdd.map(rdd -> {
    ......
    ObjectDomain domain = partialObjectDomain.getValue().get(id);

    domain.prepareData();

});
```

ObjectDomain.java

```
    public ObjectDomain implements Serializable {

        private transient EntityMaps entityMaps;

        ......

        public void prepareData() {

            // logged persons here and the succeed and failed run seem to be the same.
            new EntityMapLoader<Person>().load(persons, entityMaps.personMap); 

            ......

            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                if(employee.getPersonId() != null) {
                    // this is the line throwing error
                    Person person = entityMaps.personMap.get(employee.getPersonId());  
                    employee.setPerson(person);
                }
            }

        }
        ......
    }

    class EntityMaps {

        EntityMap<Person> personMap= new EntityMap<Person>();
        ......
    }


    class EntityMapLoader<E extends IEntity> {

        public void load(List<E> data, EntityMap<E> entityMap) {
            for (E d : data) {
                entityMap.add(d);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sometime, the spark run failed due to the line I marked (not always). It threw RunTimeException saying "Entity not found". But if I ran second time, it will be OK. I compared the failed and succeeded runs, it seems they are loading the same persons into the EntityMap. Note that we run above spark job parallel with different set of groups. Those occasionally failed times are when we run parallel. The 2nd time run (always succeed) after failure is just run the failed group. Don't want to mis-lead, but that makes me think maybe my EntityMap is not somehow "thread-safe", so it messed other groups' map. Is it possible?

To help understand the code, I also post the EntityMap class below

EntityMap.java

```
public EntityMap extends <T extends IEntity> {

    protected Map<Integer, T> entityMap;

    ......

    public void add(T entity) {
        this.entityMap.put(entity.getId(), entity);
    }

    public T get(int id) {
        T entity = this.entityMap.get(id);
        if (entity==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Entity not found");
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: one pattern we noticed is that once the failure occurs, it keep occurring. So our Ops team break the failed thread run to two threads (we schedule this job for multiple threads for different groups), now it start to work fine again. But no one knows why and I doubt that solves the actual issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `Broadcast` correctly? Broadcast variables are read-only variables. Seems like you're doing a lot in that `ObjectDomain ` https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html

Comment: @LuckyGuess, thanks for your comments. We do load all necessary data from the db before we hit the declaration of this Broadcast var and put them into a <id, ObjectDomain> map. After get into the node, we get the corresponding data and do some data preparation. I add the statement where load the data from db into the original question. Did you see anywhere suspicious?